# Prevent node save

Tags: 8

is there a way to prevent node from being saved? I want to save values form this content type into user profile fields and other profile module fields. Thank you

My code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function hospitator_qr_decode_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_time_tracker_form') {

    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
        $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'hospitator_qr_decode_form_submit';
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements custom form submit. Try to prevent node save.
 *
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 */
function hospitator_qr_decode_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('hospitator_user_interface.main_page');

  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('Form Custom Submited'), 'status');
  //How to don't save the node?

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to replace the existing submit handlers with your own?

This adds a submit handler:

```
$form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'hospitator_qr_decode_form_submit';
```

This replaces the submit handlers:

```
$form['actions'][$action]['#submit'] = ['hospitator_qr_decode_form_submit'];
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm!